# stripe.js magenetic card reader php

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, magnetic-cards

Have a web php web app for POS. Looking to see if its possible to integrate the stripe.js in order to take the details from the card and process in the transaction.

Card reader is audio jack like the ones you see from Square or Cardflight but I want to run this over the web rather than build an iOS / Android app for it.

Is it possible for the magnetic card reader to input the info it a form if the fields are in focus?

Or to do something more behind the scenes. I know being a web app this may not be possible but need to now for sure.

Any ideas?

----Edit----

I would prefer not to put the details into a webform if possible that was just the simplest solution I thought. Would it be possible to do this with the stripe.js and the card reader? Trying to get away from having to build a custom iOS / Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to input into a web form via an audio-based card reader. Your best bet would be to investigate readers which produce keyboard input as their output, similar to how  most barcode reaaders work. With one of those, you could use a standard input box and then process the input into whatever format you need.

Comment: I have edited my q. Would prefer not to use webform was just thinking if that's an option. Do you know if it could be done client side without the webform?

Comment: In theory you could use WebRTC to read from the microphone, but instead of the mic, you'd use the reader as the input device. It's a long shot though. You'd also have to figure out some way to process the signal into something that you can send to stripe