# iOS Webview app data from magnetic card reader (audio jack)

Tags: ios, webview, stripe-payments, magnetic-cards

So I asked this question... [stripe.js magenetic card reader php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476685/stripe-js-magenetic-card-reader-php)

I have a PHP POS app which can be access from the central location view a browsers, all data can be entered and its works well. Looking to make it more mobile with the use of a audio jack card reader for iPad / iPhone (similar to square). The problem is I do not want to make a separate native app. If I was to run the app in a WebView based iOS app would it be possible to interact with the audio jack and get the data to put into the Stripe payment transaction?

Hopefully that not too vague. Will try my best to explain further if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with just webviews. Native side of your app should interact with hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possibile. But, you can develope an iOS app that interact with audio and that have a webview inside.